# Appropriate pattern for indexing a container using a custom type

Tags: c++

I have a class `Id` that identifies elements in a custom container, but want to be able to use `Id` to index into unrelated random access containers as well (e.g., `std::vector`). `Id`s have a well defined mapping to an index, so the simplest solution would be to add a conversion operator to `size_t`, which would allow the following syntax:

```
Id id;
std::vector<int> array;

...

array[id] = 42;
```

I don't really want `Id` to be generally convertible to `size_t` though, I just want to be able to use it for indexing into other containers.

I've come up with the following alternatives

```
// Same problem as above, although a bit more explicit:
array[id.toIndex()] = 42;

// Accomplishes what I want, but seems a bit backwards:
id.indexInto(array) = 42;
id[array] = 42;
```

What other patterns are there to allow this sort of use? Or should I just live with one of the above or `Id` being convertible to `size_t`?

Comment: What about an _explicit_ conversion operator? `array[static_cast<size_t>(id)]` or `array[size_t(id)]`.

Comment: @zenith That's pretty similar to the `id.toIndex()` variant. It still allows generally converting `id` into a `size_t`.

Comment: How does `.toIndex()` not allow general conversion? Anyway, I like `.toIndex()` the most. It's clear about what's happening.

Comment: It may be viable to not use ` std::vector` in the first place but rather a `std::map<Id, int>`. Of course, that gets you all the (dis-)advantages which `std::map` has in comparison with `std::vector`, but maybe that's not a problem for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three choices:

1. Implicit conversion as you stated with `operator std::size_t()`
2. Explicit conversion with `explicit operator std::size_t()`, which would allow `std::size_t(id)` and `static_cast<std::size_t>(id)`
3. Custom specialized method
4. Have a custom function `access`, which is friend with `Id` and is able to call `operator[]` on any container that supports it with the `std::size_t` version

In the first three cases you'll have that `Id` will be always convertible to `std::size_t` either implicitly or explicitly. In the last case you have that that conversion is only allowed within the function(s) you specify.

An example for the last one would be:

```
class Id {
public:
    Id(std::size_t id) : inner(id) {}

    template<typename Container>
    friend typename Container::value_type& access(Container& container, Id index) {
        return container[index.inner];
    }
private:
    std::size_t inner;
};
```

then used as:

```
auto ix = Id(2);
std::vector<int> vector{1, 2, 3, 4};
std::cout << access(vector, ix);
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2198a42ae4dac03b)

Comment: Your choice 4 gave me another idea: creating a wrapper class for the container that provides `operator[](Id)`. I think that's what I'll end up using, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using something like `toIndex()` seems good. From a design perspective, do you really want to use vector? `std::map` is what you actually want to use here. Something like

```
std::map<Id, int> myData;
```

You will need to implement comparison operator(less than operator) in Id class to get this working nicely.

I cannot say how that fits in with your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but using std::map has quite a few disadvantages over std::vector, most especially that the lookup is logarithmic rather than constant. Since `Id` is easily convertible into an index (it is actually an index into a member of the custom container), I'd like to keep things O(1) and in the simplest possible memory layout.

Comment: @Paani If you are referring to `std::unordered_map`, accessing an element is O(n), not O(1). On average it's theta(1), which is probably what you meant.

Comment: @ʎǝɹɟɟɟǝſ: Hmm, you are right in the strict formal sense. But practically, it should be O(1) **if the hash function is doing it's job**.